# How to register Swagger endpoints in Flasgger

Tags: flask, swagger, openapi, flasgger

Currently using Swagger/Flasgger/Flask to document APIs/routes in an app.

```py
# app.py
from flask import Flask
from flasgger import Swagger
from myapp.blueprints.main import main

app = Flask(__name__)    
app.register_blueprint(main)
swag = Swagger(app)
```

```py
# myapp.blueprints.main.views.py
main = Blueprint('main', __name__)    

@main.route('/user/<path:user_id>', methods=['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
@main.route('/user', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def user(user_id=None):
    pass
```

To get documentation on two routes used for the same function, I need to do two things per the [Flasgger documentation](https://github.com/flasgger/flasgger#handling-multiple-http-methods-and-routes-for-a-single-function):

1. Add a `@swag_from` declaration pointing to the file that contains the spec.
2. Give the `@main.route` and `@swag_from` the same `endpoint` kwarg.

When I do step 1, I start seeing the spec information in the Swagger output:

```py
# myapp.blueprints.main.views.py
@main.route('/user/<path:user_id>', methods=['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
@main.route('/user', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@swag_from('user_without_id.yml')
def user(user_id=None):
    pass
```

```js
// > curl localhost:8000/apispec_1.json
{
"definitions": {
    "User": {
      "properties": {
        "age": {
          "default": "180", 
          "description": "The user age (should be integer)", 
          "type": "integer"
        }, 
        "tags": {
          "default": [
            "wizard", 
            "hogwarts", 
            "dead"
          ], 
          "description": "optional list of tags", 
          "items": {
            "type": "string"
          }, 
          "type": "array"
        }, 
        "username": {
          "default": "Sirius Black", 
          "description": "The user name.", 
          "type": "string"
        }
      }, 
      "required": [
        "username", 
        "age"
      ]
    }
  }, 
  "info": {
    "description": "The test-swagger-api spec", 
    "termsOfService": "/tos", 
    "title": "test-swagger-api", 
    "version": "1.0"
  }, 
  "paths": {
    "/user": {
      "get": {
        "description": "The default payload is invalid, try it, then change the age to a valid integer and try again<br/>", 
        "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "body", 
            "name": "body", 
            "required": true, 
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/User"
            }
          }
        ], 
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "A single user item", 
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/User"
            }
          }
        }, 
        "summary": "Test validation using JsonSchema"
      }, 
      "post": {
        "description": "The default payload is invalid, try it, then change the age to a valid integer and try again<br/>", 
        "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "body", 
            "name": "body", 
            "required": true, 
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/User"
            }
          }
        ], 
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "A single user item", 
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/User"
            }
          }
        }, 
        "summary": "Test validation using JsonSchema"
      }
    }, 
    "/user/{user_id}": {
      "get": {
        "description": "The default payload is invalid, try it, then change the age to a valid integer and try again<br/>", 
        "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "body", 
            "name": "body", 
            "required": true, 
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/User"
            }
          }
        ], 
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "A single user item", 
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/User"
            }
          }
        }, 
        "summary": "Test validation using JsonSchema"
      }
    }
  }, 
  "swagger": "2.0"
}
```

However, as soon as I add the `endpoint` and `methods` kwargs, my output loses the spec:

```py
# myapp.blueprints.main.views.py
@main.route('/user/<path:user_id>', methods=['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
@main.route('/user', endpoint='my-new-endpoint', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@swag_from('user_without_id.yml', endpoint='my-new-endpoint', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def user(user_id=None):
    pass
```

```js
// > curl localhost:8000/apispec_1.json
{
  "definitions": {}, 
  "info": {
    "description": "The test-swagger-api spec", 
    "termsOfService": "/tos", 
    "title": "test-swagger-api", 
    "version": "1.0"
  }, 
  "paths": {}, 
  "swagger": "2.0"
}
```

Not sure where the documentation is going.  Flasgger's [blueprint example](https://github.com/flasgger/flasgger/blob/master/examples/example_blueprint.py) doesn't show how to make this work with [multiple routes on a single function](https://github.com/flasgger/flasgger#handling-multiple-http-methods-and-routes-for-a-single-function).

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55109061/3316036

`@swag_from` needs to contain the blueprint name in its `endpoint` field which is unfortunately not clear from the `flasgger` docs.

```
# myapp.blueprints.main.views.py
@main.route('/user/<path:user_id>', methods=['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
@main.route('/user', endpoint='my-new-endpoint', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@swag_from('user_without_id.yml', endpoint='main.my-new-endpoint', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def user(user_id=None):
    pass
```